# Acessing a row in a matrix with comparing the values of the first column

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

I want to access a specific row of a matrix by comparing a user defined parameter to the values of the first column.

Pseudo Code For example:

```
parameter Real userinput;
Real matrix[4,10] = [10,1,3,5; 3,1,5,9;.....];
Integer rowidentity;

for i in 1:10 loop
 if matrix[1,i] = userinput then
   i = rowidentity;
 end if;
end for;
```

From what i know for loops or if statements dont work outside the equation part.

How can i do this task without if or for loops?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write a function that does this returning i. The matrix as input. Then use it in an equation section.

```
function getIndex
  input Real userinput;
  input Real matrix[4,10] = [10,1,3,5; 3,1,5,9;.....];
  output Integer rowidentity;
algorithm
for i in 1:10 loop
 if matrix[1,i] == userinput then
   rowidentity := i;
   return;
 end if;
end for;
end getIndex;
```

Comment: But this cant be used for parametrisation am i right?

Comment: If all the inputs of the functions are parameters you could use it to define other parameters (it should be evaluated at compile time). Even better if you make the inputs constants.

Comment: Whether the function is evaluated at compile time or not will in Dymola depend on whether you evaluate the parameters or not. However, even if it is not evaluated at compile time you can still use it for parameterization.

Comment: Yes, Hans is right, you need annotation(Evaluate=true) on the parameters you want them to be evaluated at compile time (i was lazy with my explanation).